# How to calculate how much of an element is off screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need something to calculate how much of the element is off screen—only
in the top and bottom of it.

I'm using a snippet to see if the element is partially visible,
so I just need to know how much of it is not visible.

I know it's something between the `currenTop`, element height and the size
of what the user can see, but I think I'm missing something.

Comment: .position() method may come handy. It returns top and left position of an element. Bottom can be calculated adding the outerHeight of the element with position().top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect) method and run calculations based on page position. The answer is detailed excellently in the question [Retrieve the position (X,Y) of an HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element).

Comment: Thanks!, this seems to be the way to go!.